# How to find the entry point(or base address) of a process - take care of ASLR

Tags: dll-injection

Because of ASLR(Address space layout randomization, since Windows Vista), the base address of an exe is random, so it can't be found in PE file anymore.

In Visual C++ now the /DYNAMICBASE option is default enabled, so the base address
of an exe is random - everytime the loader loads it, it happens.

After did some research on google, I am trying to use this pattern,
But it doesn't work.

Please have a look at this simple code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo = {0};
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};

    if (CreateProcessA("UseCase01.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation))
    {
        std::vector<HMODULE> buf(128);
        DWORD needed = 0;
        for (;;) {
            if (EnumProcessModulesEx(processInformation.hProcess, &buf[0], DWORD(buf.size()*sizeof(HMODULE)), &needed, LIST_MODULES_ALL) == FALSE) {
                DWORD ec = GetLastError();
                std::cout << ec << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (needed <= buf.size() * sizeof(HMODULE)) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                const size_t oldSize = buf.size();
                buf.resize(oldSize * 2);
            }
        }
        ResumeThread(processInformation.hThread);
    }
}
```

My OS is Windows 7 64bit pro, my compiler is VS2013, this is a 32bit console program, and the UseCase01.exe is also a 32bit console program too.

EnumProcessModulesEx always fails, the error code returned by GetLastError() is 299, MSDN says what about this error code: ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY, "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."

About this error code, on the EnumProcessModules's page of MSDN, "If this function is called from a 32-bit application running on WOW64, it can only enumerate the modules of a 32-bit process. If the process is a 64-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299)."

But I am sure my program is 32bit, And, I tested on 64bit program, it fails with error 299 too, so it doesn't make sence.

"The handle returned by the CreateProcess function has PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS access to the process object." - from MSDN, so it can't be a access rights problem ?

Then I try to use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, it fails with error code 299 too, both 32bit and 64bit.

I just can't figure it out.

My goal is find the entry point of the sub-process in a safe way, whatever it's 32bit or 64bit process.

I found this is the "deepest" answer about this question: http://winprogger.com/getmodulefilenameex-enumprocessmodulesex-failures-in-wow64/

Unfortunately, 64bit program will fails too, not only for Wow64, so it doesn't make sence.

If this is infeasible, what is the good way (find base address or entry point of a suspended sub-process)?

Comment: "entry point of the sub-process" do you mean `main` (or `WinMain`) in the executable? Why not use `dumpbin` or the APIs for reading a PE executable? Summary: this sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&ei=lcCBVKX_E4r5ULu6geAP&usg=AFQjCNG6PdyCWEgR_NXZkL96ZR4G9aJ-wA&sig2=B5Bex9sUiMUvmpTYVyV_hw&bvm=bv.80642063,d.d24): why do you want the entry point?

Comment: @Richard entry point is usually mainCRTStatup(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx), it's before main. I want entry point because the next step is patch it, prepare for DLL injection, DLL injection is another story.

Comment: Why do you need to patch the entry point to "prepare for DLL injection"? What are you preparing exactly? DLL injection does not usually require prior preparation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To patch the entry point with "jmp short $", so the process will "stop" at the ep, after this, do the injection. The process is suspended at very early, if it not get the ep, some initialization will not be done. CreateRemoteThread do the LoadLibrary and call function job will not be safe.  https://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/injecting-dll-into-process-on-load/

Comment: So what's the problem? That Wordpress article you linked to shows exactly how to find and patch the entry point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because of ASLR as I said above, it will not works anymore, the base address of exe is random, you can't find it in PE, it depends on loader.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EnumProcessModulesEx and CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fails - whatever 32bit or 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331014/enumprocessmodulesex-and-createtoolhelp32snapshot-fails-whatever-32bit-or-64bi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the process suspended. While the key kernel data structures will be created, no modules will be loaded (that would involve executing code in module entry points (`dllmain`)).

Thus the error makes sense: the data structures to track modules loaded will be empty, and quite possibly not allocated at all.

Comment: I removed CREATE_SUSPENDED flag and after CreateProcess I inserted a Sleep(100), the sub-process runs, and it's error 299 again. btw CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fails 299 too.

Comment: Try using `WaitForInputIdle()` instead of `Sleep()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually I need it to be suspended.

Comment: Well, as you already discovered, you can't enumerate the modules when you create it suspected. You will have to find another solution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried WaitForInputIdle, the process runs up, and enum modules fails with error 299, so suspended is just not the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tested the program again, without CREATE_SUSPENDED flag and give it a Sleep(1000), keep the child-process running for a while, and you're right, there is no error code 299 now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I choosed the IPC solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

On all Windows operating systems (32/64bit):

```
DWORD ImageBaseAddress = ((LPDWORD)PEB)[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some wait it will help you it looks currently resource is not available.