# EnumProcessModulesEx and CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fails - whatever 32bit or 64bit

Tags: winapi, dll-injection

Edit:

The answer of this question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27317947/996540

When you create a project in msvc, the option /DYNAMICBASE is default enabled
now. Because of ASLR(Address space layout randomization, since Windows Vista),
everytime you run an exe, it's load address is random.

I am doing the DLL injection job recently, so I did some research into it on
google, and have read some projects. Get the load address (base address) of an
exe is important.

It seems there're two simple APIs to do this: EnumProcessModulesEx and
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot. But I never succeeded.

So this is the code sample:

```
void TestEnumProcessModulesEx(const char* app)
{
    std::cout << "Begin TestEnumProcessModulesEx(" << mybit() << ")" << std::endl;

    STARTUPINFOA startupInfo = {0};
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};

    if (CreateProcessA(app, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation))
    {
        std::vector<HMODULE> buf(128);
        DWORD needed = 0;
        for (;;) {
            if (EnumProcessModulesEx(processInformation.hProcess, &buf[0], DWORD(buf.size()*sizeof(HMODULE)), &needed, LIST_MODULES_ALL) == FALSE) {
                DWORD ec = GetLastError();
                std::cout << "GetLastError() = " << ec << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (needed <= buf.size() * sizeof(HMODULE)) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                const size_t oldSize = buf.size();
                buf.resize(oldSize * 2);
            }
        }
        ResumeThread(processInformation.hThread);
        WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }

    std::cout << "End TestEnumProcessModulesEx(" << mybit() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

To reduce the length of this Question, the complete code - including the
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot's test code - is not listed here, but you can get it
from:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/235920/enum_proc_mods_sample.7z
or
https://www.mediafire.com/?cry3pnra8392099

"If this function is called from a 32-bit application running on WOW64, it can
only enumerate the modules of a 32-bit process. If the process is a 64-bit
process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
(299)." - from MSDN.

And this is a blog post about this question:
http://winprogger.com/getmodulefilenameex-enumprocessmodulesex-failures-in-wow64/

Unfortunately, this does not make sence, because whatever the specified
process is 32bit or 64bit, it fails with 299; whatever the caller process is
32-bit or 64bit, it fails with 299.

This is the output of my sample:

```
Begin TestEnumProcessModulesEx(32bit)
GetLastError() = 299
hello world 32bit
End TestEnumProcessModulesEx(32bit)

Begin TestEnumProcessModulesEx(32bit)
GetLastError() = 299
hello world 64bit
End TestEnumProcessModulesEx(32bit)

Begin TestEnumProcessModulesEx(64bit)
GetLastError() = 299
hello world 32bit
End TestEnumProcessModulesEx(64bit)

Begin TestEnumProcessModulesEx(64bit)
GetLastError() = 299
hello world 64bit
End TestEnumProcessModulesEx(64bit)
```

As you see, any combination is failed.

My OS is Windows 7 64bit pro and my compiler is VS2013.

So, what can I do ?

Comment: "If the module list in the target process is corrupted or not yet initialized ... EnumProcessModulesEx may fail or return incorrect information" - perhaps because the process has been created in a suspended state, it has not run at all and so its module list is "not yet initialized" ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter So I have removed CREATE_SUSPENDED, let the process run, but it still fails with 299.

Comment: @JonathanPotter You are right. Today I have tested the program again, without CREATE_SUSPENDED flag, keep the child-process running for a while, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the unsuccess of EnumProcessModulesEx and
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, let's leave this question to the expert.

My goal is to get the load address (base address) of the child process, find
the entry point and patch it - the reason to patch the entry point is here:
https://opcode0x90.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/injecting-dll-into-process-on-load/

Since DLL injection is the main purpose of mine, I have to reconsider this
question. I would use the "CreateRemoteThread & LoadLibrary Technique"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_2
to do the DLL injection (In fact ASLR is not the barrier of this technique by the way),
Although there are so many limits in DLLMain
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
, but do a little works is OK: Find the base address of an exe using
GetModuleHandleA(NULL), save the HMODULE returned into shared memory,
next, the caller process read shared memory and get the HMODULE.
Synchronization mechanism is necessary of course.

So, the answer is IPC. (not every IPC mechanism is safe in DLLMain by the way)