# Can't unload an injected dll with loadlibrary (C++)

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary, dll-injection

Today I got an LoadLibraryA injector that works perfectly but it doesn't let delete the dll after injection (loadlibrary things) and I tried doing FreeLibraryAndExitThread but it didnt work.

The code I tried:
`FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hThread, 0);`

The injection code:

```
            const char* procName = "notepad.exe";
            DWORD procID = 0;

            while (!procID)
            {
                procID = GetProcID(procName);
                Sleep(30);
            }

            HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, procID);

            if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

                if (loc)
                {
                    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);
                }

                HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);

                if (hThread)
                {
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                }

                if (hProc)
                {
                    CloseHandle(hProc);
                }
                
                FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hThread, 0);

                return 0;
            }
```

btw sorry for stupid questions, I'm new to cpp and didn't find an solution in internet that does work.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` should be called with the `hLibModule` (returned by `LoadLibrary`, `LoadLibraryEx`, `GetModuleHandle` or `GetModuleHandleEx`). I don't think `CreateRemoteThread` returns a compatible handle.

Comment: So if I switch to LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx I can unload the dll?

Comment: You can't just switch functions. `CreateRemoteThread` creates a thread, `LoadLibrary` loads a `DLL`. I've never done DLL injection, so I'm not sure where the library gets loaded in your scenario.

Comment: I mean, switch the entire injection code.

Comment: That I don't know. I've never done injection.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your attention.

Comment: You're welcome. With a [mcve] I (and many others) would probably be spending even more time on it.

Comment: I believe `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` must be called from within the client process.

Comment: `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` is not what you need in this situation anyway, even if called in the remote process.

Answer (score 1):

You are not unloading the DLL correctly.

You are misusing `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()`.  It expects an `HMODULE` of a loaded DLL to unload, but you are giving it the `HANDLE` of the remote thread instead - which you have already closed via `CloseHandle()` beforehand.  And in any case, `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` terminates the *calling* thread, which is not what you want to do in this situation.

You need to wait for `LoadLibrary()` to fully complete.  After creating the remote thread, wait on the thread `HANDLE` using `WaitForSingleObject()` or related function.

After that, you can then inject a call to [`FreeLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibrary) into the context of the remote process, passing it the `HMODULE` that `LoadLibrary()` returned - which you currently do not have.  When using `LoadLibrary()` as a thread procedure, the thread's exit code will contain the returned `HMODULE`.  If your target is a 32-bit process, you can use [`GetExitCodeThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodethread) to retrieve that `HMODULE`.  But things get more complicated if your target is a 64-bit process, since the thread's exit code will truncate the `HMODULE` value.

See [CreateRemoteThread on LoadLibrary and get the HMODULE back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332509/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what do you want but you can't do it because you closed the handle:

```
if (hThread)
{
     CloseHandle(hThread);
} 
...

FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hThread, 0);
```